# Wordpress .htaccess header security doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I modify my `.htaccess` file as shown on this link: https://really-simple-ssl.com/site-health-recommended-security-headers/ but the problem being that it still does not work, when I do an analysis of my site with this online tool: https://www.getastra.com/, the one continues to say that I have not secured the headers of my site.

Here is the content of my .htaccess file :

```
# Really Simple SSL
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"
Header always set Expect-CT "max-age=7776000, enforce"
Header always set Referrer-Policy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
Header always set Permissions-Policy: "" 
# End Really Simple SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
# Directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are generated
# dynamically, and should only be changed through WordPress filters.
# Any changes to directives between these markers will be overridden.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Comment: Give us the URL of your site then, so that we can at least check for ourselves whether that tool actually tells the truth.

Comment: @CBroe https://devone.be/, can you tell me the path to follow for verify this?

Comment: Well first of all I would use browser dev tools to verify things like this, the network panel shows you all headers. In this instance, I looks to me like the headers are present for all embedded resources (JS, CSS, images) - but not for the main document itself. But why that would be the case, I couldn't tell you right now. Might have to do with the fact that the former are static assets, whereas the page itself gets rendered via PHP. Or maybe due to some caching plugin.

Comment: Alright, this is where I was checking. 
So, you don't know why my headers are not visible while my ```.htaccess``` file is configured well?

Comment: Like I said, they _are_ visible for the static resources. Why (apparently) not for the dynamically created content (pages/posts themselves), I can't tell you with the information at hand, that will need some further investigating.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still didn't find the answer, I had the same issue with my website, I tried to purge my website's cache using the LiteSpeedCache plugin and it worked!

Comment: I contacted my hosting company directly to find a solution with them, they fixed the problem on their side. I advise you to do the same.